# Is there a jQuery EventSource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, server-sent-events

Server Sent Events seem like a prime candidate for a jQuery plug-in.  Page 921 of JavaScript, the Definitive Guide shows how to use EventSource.  But then page 923 says that IE uses attachEvent instead of addEventListener.

I found [jQuery.EventSource](https://github.com/rwldrn/jquery.eventsource/wiki) on github, but there's no mention of attachEvent. It instead falls back to using $.ajax.

Q: If I'm going to use the EventSource feature of JavaScript, should I use jQuery.EventSource?

I gotta have more jQuery!

Comment: There is also https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource and https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js, but I'm not sure what each does over native EventSource.

Comment: upvoted for presumed cowbell reference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of today IE9 doesn't support EventSource (Server Sent Events). In the good article by Remy Sharp, there is at the end of the article a [list of polyfill solutions](http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/).